# Numpy check if a matrix can be transformed to another matrix by swaping columns

Tags: numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

Say we have matrix `A` and `B` as follow

```
>>> A
matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> B
matrix([[0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Clearly we can "transform" matrix A to B by column swapping. Is there an efficient algorithm to check whether two (potentially large) matrices can be transformed to each other in this way?

Comment: Sort by column and check if the resulting matrices are equal.

Comment: Is it just rolling or there could be *proper* swapping? It seems rolling for the given sample as `B = A[:,[2,3,0,1]]`.

Comment: @kazemakase thanks! that should work. Didn't know numpy provides a matrix sort method

Comment: @kazemakase That should probably be an answer

Comment: @Divakar sorry, could you explain the difference between rolling and swapping? I might be using the wrong term.

Comment: Well `B` could be thought of as starting from the col-2 of `A` and rolling over at the end and starting from 0, i.e. cols of A that are taken in order would be : col-2, col-3, then starting from col-0, col-1, so `A[:,[2,3,0,1]]`. Is such a pattern seen with your actual large data or its just a coincidence that the given sample here just happens to have it?

Comment: Another example of rolling would be : `B = A[:,[1,2,3,0]]`, as it rolls from col-1 onwards.

Comment: @Divakar I see what you meant. Sorry for the confusion. I should have provided more general examples. Any kind of swapping can happens, not only rolling.

Comment: Also, does the data only contain `0s` and `1s`? What's the typical shape of your actual large input arrays?

Comment: @Divakar oh they can be any real values ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function. For very large matrix, it is possible that `(A==B).all()` is slower than `np.array_equal(A,B)`.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0]])

B = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0]])

def isSwaping(a, b):
    count = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(a.T): # transpose of a
        for d in b.T:
            if (c == d).all(): 
                count += 1
                break
        if count == i : # then it is uncessary to continue
            return False
    return True

print isSwaping(A, B)
```